# Dynamic str replace with javascript on html containing stream

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have a html which looks roughly like this

```
<div id="wallPostTemplate">
    <li id='comment-content--oOo-id-oOo-' class='comment-content' comment_id='-oOo-id-oOo-'>
        <a class='comment-avatar' href='-oOo-link-oOo-'>
            <img class='small_avatar' src='<?="../" . MESTO_ZA_UPLOAD_FAJLOVA_KORISNIKA ?>-oOo-korisnikPodaci.Slika-oOo-'></a> 
            -oOo-text-oOo-
    </li>
</div>
```

Now I get the contents of the html into a sting with `$('#wallPostTemplate').text()` and then I want to replace dynamically the occurrences of the string `-oOo-id-oOo-` 
with whatever data I have stored inisde a variable like `-oOo-id-oOo-`, `-oOo-text-oOo-` and so on...

Now I tried numerous ways to tackle this thing but I always end up without a solution. 
Here is my latest try out. HELP pls Q_Q

```
var regex = new RegExp('{\-oOo\-'+index+'\-oOo\-}', "g");
post = post.replace(regex, value);
```

Also I tried `str.replace` but it does not work... It seems new lines are the problem but I have no idea how to over come this.....

edit:

To make it more simple to understand i made a example on jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/DdBFB/ 
And as you can see, you can see nothing.... it dous not work when you get the content over the html function.

Comment: What is the main objective of replacement?

Comment: The main objective is to take a content from a div and reform it. and onlz that way, not like storing it inside a variable, that would be to tendios, becouse the code could get really bulky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not really clear I've whipped up an example that replaces a value based on a regular expression.

```
var source = "-oOo-korisnikPodaci.Slika-oOo-";
var id = "korisnikPodaci.Slika";
var regex = new RegExp('\-oOo\-' + id + '\-oOo\-', "gmi");

// Match
source.replace(regex, "hello world"); // => "Hello World"

// Mismatch
source = "-oO!!!o-korisnikPodaci.Slika-oO!!!o-";
source.replace(regex, "hello world"); // => "-oO!!!o-korisnikPodaci.Slika-oO!!!o-"
```

Comment: This will not work, all regex until now failed to make it trough the new lines which is made from the $().text() function. Al tough I did not try the "gmi" option inside the regex. Will try it... hope it helps. btw. this looks much like the code i made.

Comment: ok, i tried my code arround and it comes out i was not setting the regex flag right, i missed the multiline flag. Thank you so much, becouse of your post i figured out the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question your goal is make something like a post template that will be loaded in runtime/cliente side. So if this is really your goal you can try use the [jQuery Template Plugin](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

Sample for your case: (don´t tested yet)

```
var tmlpPost = "<div id='${postId}'>" + 
                         "      <li id='comment-content-${postId}' class='comment-content' comment_id='${postId}'>" + 
                         "              <a class='comment-avatar' href='${link}'>" + 
                         "                  img class='small_avatar' src='<?="../" . MESTO_ZA_UPLOAD_FAJLOVA_KORISNIKA ?>${korisnikPodaciSlika}'>" + 
                         "              </a> " + 
                         "              ${postText}" + 
                         "      </li>" + 
                         "</div>";


$.tmpl( tmlpPost, { "postId" : "123" , "link" : "http://posturl.com", "korisnikPodaciSlika" : "something",  "postText" : "Post text goes here..."}).appendTo( "#yourPostWall" );
```

Or using `<script>` not a `var`: [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJP6k/)

```
<script id="tmlpPost" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div id='${postId}'>
          <li id='comment-content-${postId}' class='comment-content' comment_id='${postId}'>
                  <a class='comment-avatar' href='${link}'>
                      <img class='small_avatar' src='<?="../" . MESTO_ZA_UPLOAD_FAJLOVA_KORISNIKA ?>${korisnikPodaciSlika}'>
                  </a>
                  ${postText}
          </li>
    </div>
</script>
```

Now on page load:

```
$("#tmlpPost").tmpl( { "postId" : "123" , "link" : "http://posturl.com", "korisnikPodaciSlika" : "something",  "postText" : "Post text goes here..."}).appendTo( "#output" );​
```

Comment: +1 because OP is surely trying to do templating, I'd suggest doing it server-side though.

Comment: I can not make server side templating because all data i get over jsonrpc services... which sux i know... But the problem is, the code would get to clunky if i were to make it all in the js like you did here, i posted a jsfiddle example in my original post.

Comment: The template does not have to be stored in `var` it can be done using a `<script>`. See the answer change.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i figured the answer was that i set the regex flags wrong, so i went to jsfiddle and fiddled with it and you can see the answer there :)

http://jsfiddle.net/DdBFB/11/

I was missing the multi line flag Q_Q....im no good with regex even in php not to speak in js...

Comment: It would be nice if you included the code here so people can see it and in case the external site deletes the content.